# KCfinder upload image for many users

Tags: php

My website lets logged users to use CKeditor and CKFinder to create pages or blog and of course upload image from editor. I got problem for many users that will use the same images in a single folder. I have searching for the same problem on StackOverflow and I found this question:
[KCFinder with CKEditor - setting up dynamic folders for upload files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211453/kcfinder-with-ckeditor-setting-up-dynamic-folders-for-upload-files).

I think the solution was good, but rather than creating many folders, I am just thinking how to save every user images by using a prefix of their user ID. For example the user with ID 10 will save his images with prefix `10_xxxxx.jpg` and so on.

How to do it. Any body could show me where part of the file script that could be modified? I am using KCFinder V.3.12. Sorry for my English.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = 10;

public function upload() {
        $config = &$this->config;
        $file = &$this->file;
        $url = $message = "";

        if ($config['disabled'] || !$config['access']['files']['upload']) {
            if (isset($file['tmp_name'])) @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
            $message = $this->label("You don't have permissions to upload files.");

        } elseif (true === ($message = $this->checkUploadedFile())) {
            $message = "";

            $dir = "{$this->typeDir}/";
            if (isset($_GET['dir']) &&
                (false !== ($gdir = $this->checkInputDir($_GET['dir'])))
            ) {
                $udir = path::normalize("$dir$gdir");
                if (substr($udir, 0, strlen($dir)) !== $dir)
                    $message = $this->label("Unknown error.");
                else {
                    $l = strlen($dir);
                    $dir = "$udir/";
                    $udir = substr($udir, $l);
                }
            }

            if (!strlen($message)) {
                if (!is_dir(path::normalize($dir)))
                    @mkdir(path::normalize($dir), $this->config['dirPerms'], true);

                $filename = $this->normalizeFilename($file['name']);
                $target = file::getInexistantFilename($dir . $filename);

                if (!@move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target) &&
                    !@rename($file['tmp_name'], $target) &&
                    !@copy($file['tmp_name'], $target)
                )
                    $message = $this->label("Cannot move uploaded file to target folder.");
                else {
                    if (function_exists('chmod'))
                        @chmod($target, $this->config['filePerms']);
                    $this->makeThumb($target);
                    $url = $this->typeURL;
                    if (isset($udir)) $url .= "/$udir";
                    $url .= "/" . basename($target);
                    if (preg_match('/^([a-z]+)\:\/\/([^\/^\:]+)(\:(\d+))?\/(.+)$/', $url, $patt)) {
                        list($unused, $protocol, $domain, $unused, $port, $path) = $patt;
                        $base = "$protocol://$domain" . (strlen($port) ? ":$port" : "") . "/";
                        $url = $base . path::urlPathEncode($path);
                    } else
                        $url = path::urlPathEncode($url);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Just concatenate ID from `$_SESSION` array and the filename.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy First, I tried to add $filename = '10_'.$filename; but not making the different. I have no idea to continue by  using session